# Organizing static functions in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am building application in node js using mongodb. I am using mongoose as ODM.
The problem is I have lot of static functions in mongoose model which are attached to schema.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    profile: {
      firstName: { type: String },
      lastName: { type: String }
    },
    auth:{
      username:{ type: String },
      password:{ type: String }
    },
    account:{
      status:{ type: Boolean, default: false }
    }
 });

userSchema.statics.function1 = function(params, callback){
    //some operation
}

userSchema.statics.function2 = function(params, callback){
    //some operation
}

userSchema.statics.function3 = function(params, callback){
    //some operation
}

userSchema.statics.function4 = function(params, callback){
    //some operation
}

//.... upto 50 to 70 static functions


var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Is there a way to write these functions in another file(or module) and import and attach them to schema.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but maybe just group together the statics in one file and assigning them to the statics property in the schema? Also, perhaps you could use query builder to query your db instead of creating very specific statics.